# Change axes to polar on Matlab figure

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix it Matlab that results in a circular contour plot
[image: Circular contour plot]

Is there any way to change the axess from rectangular to polar without changing the shape of the graph?

Comment: Have you ever tried [theta,rho] = cart2pol(x,y)

Comment: It's rather unclear what you are trying to accomplish. What would each point in this matrix represent then if this is not rectangular?